# how can I draw a vertical line between two specific columns in multicol environment

Tags: rules, multicol

Trying to have a vertical line between the 4th and the 5th column in a multicol environment.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%opening


\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{5}

\lipsum
%... line_beween_forth_and_fith_column
\end{multicols}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you want, looks like you try to reinvent the wheel. Why don't you use `\begin{tabular}{cccc|c}` this way you get a table with a line between the 4th and 5th column

Answer (score 5):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%opening

\makeatletter
\setlength\columnseprule{.5pt}

\def\columnseprulecolor\vrule\@width{%
\ifnum\count@=\numexpr\mult@rightbox+8\relax
\vrule\@width
\else
\kern
\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{5}

\lipsum
%... line_beween_forth_and_fith_column
\end{multicols}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Using a delimited macro to patch is sneaky :-) and perhaps stating how the 8 comes about might help.

Comment: looks great, but could you explain the macro?

Comment: @user30424 in the depths of `multicol` is the code sequence `\columnseprulecolor\vrule\@width\columnseprule` which draws a rule default width 0) of the specified color (default black) by setting the rule width to .5pt rules appear but I abuse `\columseprulecolor` to test the column number and replace the rule by a kern (horizontal space) except for the specified column. The relevant counter changes by 2 each time starting at `\mult@rightbox` hence the +8 for column 4 This might not be a fully documented interface in Frank's code but it works well enough here.